# Non-Blog Website without Search: are comments.php and search.php in theme still required?

Tags: theme-development, search, comments-template

What is the best practice when it comes to a static, minimal WP website? It will have no blog updates, no discussion/comments, and no search. Should all the standard template files still be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/#required-files), the only *required* files in a theme are `style.css` and `index.php`. All other files are optional. You can use the ones you need and discard the ones you don't need.

If you haven't seen it, I'd recommend you check out WordPress's [developer site](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) on the topic of themes.

Comment: Hadn't seen that site, thank you